# jQuery Validation Plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I'd like a hint to solve a problem I've been experiencing, I have two functions, the first validates the form and the second is the post to a PHP file.

The problem is that the form is being sent before being validated. I wonder if it is possible to combine these two functions, ie, validate first and only if everything is correct to the form submission. Anyone know how?

Validation Function

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$('#singup-form').validate(
        {
            rules: {
                user_name: {
                    minlength: 3,
                    required: true
                },
                user_email: {
                    required: true,
                    email: true
                },
                user_password: {
                    required: true

                },
                confirmation_password: {
                    required: true,
                    equalTo: '#user_password'
                },
                user_phone: {
                    number: true,
                    minlength: 8
                },
                user_twitter: {
                    minlength: 3
                },
                agree: {
                    required: true
                }
            },
            highlight: function(label) {
                $(label).closest('.control-group').removeClass('success').addClass('error');
            },
            success: function(label) {
                label
                        .text('OK!').addClass('valid')
                        .closest('.control-group').removeClass('error').addClass('success');

            }
        });
}); // end document.ready
```

function post

```
$('#singup-form-submit').click(function(e) {
$.post("register", {
    user_name: $('#user_name').val(),
    user_email: $('#user_email').val(),
    user_password: $('#user_password').val(),
    confirmation_password: $('#confirmation_password').val(),
    user_ddd: $('#user_ddd').val(),
    user_phone: $('#user_phone').val(),
    user_twitter: $('#user_twitter').val(),
    agree: $('#agree').val()
}, function(data) {

    $('#resultado').html(data);
});
e.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is how you would combine your two functions (*of course, assuming your two functions are already operating correctly*). Nothing inside of the `submitHandler` fires until the form is valid.  As per [documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#toptions), this is where you'd put any ajax functionality.

Use the built-in `submitHandler:` as follows.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#singup-form').validate({
        rules: {
            user_name: {
                minlength: 3,
                required: true
            },
            user_email: {
                required: true,
                email: true
            },
            user_password: {
                required: true
            },
            confirmation_password: {
                required: true,
                equalTo: '#user_password'
            },
            user_phone: {
                number: true,
                minlength: 8
            },
            user_twitter: {
                minlength: 3
            },
            agree: {
                required: true
            }
        },
        highlight: function (label) {
            $(label).closest('.control-group').removeClass('success').addClass('error');
        },
        success: function (label) {
            label.text('OK!').addClass('valid').closest('.control-group').removeClass('error').addClass('success');
        },
        submitHandler: function (form) {
            $.post("register", {
                user_name: $('#user_name').val(),
                user_email: $('#user_email').val(),
                user_password: $('#user_password').val(),
                confirmation_password: $('#confirmation_password').val(),
                user_ddd: $('#user_ddd').val(),
                user_phone: $('#user_phone').val(),
                user_twitter: $('#user_twitter').val(),
                agree: $('#agree').val()
            }, function(data) {
                $('#resultado').html(data);
            });
        }
    });

}); // end document.ready
```

See documentation:

http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#toptions

> **submitHandler**,    Callback,   Default: default (native) form submit
>  Callback for handling the actual submit when the form is valid. Gets
>   the form as the only argument. Replaces the default submit. The right
>   place to submit a form via Ajax after it validated.

Comment: Thank you! worked perfectly.

Documentations are excellent for those who already know the language, but for those who are learning and need examples, is confusing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a submit handler instead of just binding the submit code to the click event.

[Plugins/Validation/validate](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate)

> Use submitHandler to implement your own form submit, eg. via Ajax.

```
$("#myform").validate({
 submitHandler: function(form) {
   form.submit();
 }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

May be this will help, I wrote my own plug-in  for jQuery cause of I need some flexibility in patterns. https://github.com/KirShur/ValidolRepo